# pass data from uicollectionview in custom tablecell to viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a problem. I have a ViewController1 contain a tableView.that tableView create a custom tableViewCell

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    TableCategoryCell *cell = (TableCategoryCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CategoryCellIndentifier];
}
```

In custom cell TableCategoryCell.m contain a collectionView.

```
-(UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell_collection = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:COLLECTION_CELL_IDENTIFIER forIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Now I want user click to collectionView item in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` method open new ViewController2 and pass data to ViewController 2?

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navigationController =[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Navigation"];
    ViewController2 *watchController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:WATCH_IDENTIFIER];
    [navigationController pushViewController:watchController animated:YES];
}
```

I can push ViewController2 from collection item in storyboard but i dont know in programming?
How can i do?

Comment: so, if you select the cell in collection view, it should push to 2nd view controller. is that what you mean?

Comment: yes..i don't know how to push to 2nd ViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the delegate method for uicollection view:

```
- (void)tableView:(UICollectionView *)tableView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   //check if you tap on cell 1
    if(inderPath.row==0){
             //then push to second view controller
            UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                                     bundle: nil];
          SecondViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"your-second-view-controller-ID"];
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    }   

}
```

Comment: I can't call self.storyboard in didSelectItemAtIndexPath? i checked event tap on cell. this is Viewcontroller2.h **@interface ViewController2 : UITableViewCell <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>**

Comment: aren't you using storyboards? I edited my answer.Try that

Comment: Yes..I using Main.storyboard, my schedule: navigationController->VC0 inserted VC1 -> push to VC2.? i Think VC1 is sub of VC0 so it can call self.storyboard.

Comment: This is storyboard [https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0imxfcYo02fYks4MlFySzRpa1E/view?usp=sharing]